# `<object>` タグ内の外部 HTML から Submit したとき、親 HTML　の更新はできますか？

Tags: html5

`<object>` タグで外部 HTML を読み込み、外部 HTML 内で Submit したときに、
親ページを更新することは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

埋め込まれた外部 HTML 内で [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.parent) オブジェクトが利用できますので、以下のようにして、親ページを参照してメソッドを呼び出すことができます。

object_parent.html:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>parent</h1>
    <object data="object_child.html"
            style="width: 400; height: 240px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
        You have no object tag support
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

object_child.html:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h2>child</h2>
    <form action="#">
        <button onclick="window.parent.location.reload()">Action!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```